# Is slack team id unique or not?

Tags: api, unique, bots, slack-api, slack

I'm making slack bots on my computer and trying to store team id to my database.

I just want to know slack's team id is unique or not.

I was trying to find it on slack docs.. but I got nothing.

Anybody knows it?

Comment: Although I have no proof I think you can safely assume that the team ID is unique. The suffix "ID" in the name suggest that it is.

Answer (score 9):

While user IDs and channel IDs aren't totally unique (they are unique only to the team that contains them), team IDs are a principal organizing force throughout Slack and are indeed unique. You'll never find two separate Slack teams with the same team ID.